# Powershell - Add folder/files to zip while excluding certain folders

Tags: powershell, zip, get-childitem

I'm trying to feed the results of a Get-ChildItem call through io.compression.zipfile to create a zip file of "E:\Applications_Server_Test", excluding two folders "BACKUP" and "BACKUP2".

However, Powershell seems to be interpreting this as "$items = a string of directories and file names" instead of a recursive collection of directories and files I want to zip. I can find tutorials on using Get-ChildItem to exclude directories and I can find tutorials on how to zip a full directory or zip multiple directories but I can't find anything on zipping directories with exclusions. Can somebody tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
$source = "E:\Applications_Server_Test"
$destination = "E:\AST_Dump.zip"

$items = Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse | ?{ $_.fullname -notmatch "\\backup\\?" }

Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($items, $destination)
```

Thanks!

Comment: See [Zipping only files using powershell](http://serverfault.com/a/456496)

Comment: I have 6 directories and 2 files in this root "Applications_Server_Test" folder.

BACKUP
BACKUP2
DIR1
DIR2
DIR3
DIR4
Genericfile.txt
Genericfile.dat

I'm only excluding the two BACKUP folders but I still want the other four folders, any recursive files and folders and the two root level files. I'd like to package those remaining files and folders into a single zip file with Powershell. Are my only options to either symbolically link everything I want somewhere else and package it or create one .zip per folder?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are trying to archive the object $items, not the folder. Unfortunately this is not gonna work. 
Try to move the backup folders at the same drive (this will just change records at the drive and not move any data), then to archive the whole "E:\Applications_Server_Test" folder and to move back the backup folders.

Other option is to use [*ZipArchive.CreateEntry*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh158346(v=vs.110).aspx) method and to add file by file in to the archive. But this is not so elegant ;)

Comment: I think it's possible to create symbolic links in a new folder for each required file, so no need to actually copy the files.

Comment: The problem is that the backup folders are part of the application. They need to stay in the same place. I'm just looking to grab the other files and folders in that root directory and zip them while leaving BACKUP and BACKUP2 alone.

Comment: Just use symlinks in a new folder: [examples](https://www.google.com/#q=powershell+create+symlink)

Comment: I appreciate the response but this seems more applicable to fixing Autosvet's answer than evaluating my question and suggesting an answer for it. Creating symbolic links instead of working with formattng for a Get-ChildItem call seems convoluted. Is it really not possible to cycle recursively through all files and folders except for two exceptions and add the non-exceptions to a zip file?

Comment: If your OS and PS version support Compress-Archive (PS 4.0 and Win 8.1 if I remember well) cmdlet you can use it:

`$items |ForEach-Object {Compress-Archive $_.FullName -DestinationPath $destination}`  

Otherwise need to create similar loop with ZipArchive.CreateEntry method that I mention in the answer.